# Is a child adopted into a mixed-race family considered mixed race as well?

Tags: adoption

I was adopted from an unknown parentage into a family of mixed heritage. I was 3 months old at the time, so I really don't think about my biological background. I certainly look like I could be from the mix of my family, but we are all fairly caucasian looking.

Now, whenever I am asked about my race - on applications, for example - I wonder if I am legally "mixed race."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asks about being "legally mixed race", which is a legal question.

Comment: I agree. I think you should ask it in the Law Stack Exchange.

Comment: While I don't think this is necessarily a perfect fit on Parenting, it would not be on-topic at Law without more specifics (e.g., jurisdiction).

Comment: It's worth noting that the majority of "black" Americans and a significant minority of "white" Americans have measurable amounts of DNA from both African and European origins, while the "Hispanic" racial category describes a varied mixture of African, European and Native American genetics.

Answer (score 3):

Legal questions would depend on the country you're asking about, as every country is different.

`Race`, as opposed to `ethnicity`, is generally considered to be a physical characteristic - i.e., it's not something that describes the culture you were raised in, but that describes yourself genetically - or at least, personally.

It is however still considered, at least in the United States, to be something you mostly define on your own.  If you consider yourself white, you are white.  If you consider yourself black, you are.  Same for mixed race.

Cases where there are exceptions to this are primarily where there are specific benefits based on race - specifically, things like scholarships.  There the scholarship may have a specific rule ("must have at least one grandparent" or similar).  But even in most of those cases it's very hard to say, and most of those are thus based on ethnicity rather than race.  Racial preferences as far as affirmative action are nearly always based on self-reported race, and thus it's up to you what you consider yourself.

If you are aware of your biological parentage, you could of course find out what race your parents are/were, and determine yours from that. If you're unaware, you should consider yourself whatever race you think is appropriate; you could consider genetic testing if you wish in order to find out what race(s) you share the most DNA with, but that is likely not necessary unless you wish to know.

Ultimately - you should make a choice based on what you feel.  Applications for jobs or university will allow you to make your own choice, and will not second-guess you for it.

Answer (score 2):

I repeat some of the previous answer and Can't reply to the answer but i wanted to give something to think about...  i am mixed race but my parents are not.    My children are mixed race but because they would only be aprox 25% non-Europid, they will probably be assumed to be Caucasian. I appear Caucasian to the majority of laymen.    You could always send a DNA sample in and have an analysis done for around $100usd.

Unless you are applying to something that is based on your race (like scholarship or tribal recognition), do whatever feels right.

[This](http://blogs.findlaw.com/law_and_life/2015/06/rachel-dolezal-lying-about-racial-identity-a-crime.html) is about that  white NAACP lady.  It may violate an employer's ethics code, but it appears that flat-out lying about your race is not illegal.

In the US it is only asked for statistical reporting and you may decline to provide any such information.
Do your birth or adoption documents have Anything that could help you?